# Xamarin.Essentials.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm quite new to programming, so please excuse some maybe dumb questions :S

I'm currently trying to implement a Multiplatform System Tray Application in Xamarin.
I found this code on GitHub and added a few things: https://github.com/krdmllr/CrossTrayApplicationSample
Now I wanted to use the Preferences from Xamarin.Essentials to store some values between closing the app. I imported Essentials via NuGet to all the projects, but when I tried using it, I always got the error
"This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation."

If more information is needed to help me, please let me know :)

Edit:

I'm trying to use the Essentials Library inside the Mainpage of my Shared-Project.

[My Solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjIiW.png)

In the Main-Page I have a simple Entry and Button:

`<Entry x:Name="location" Keyboard="Url" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Placeholder="C://" PlaceholderColor="DarkOliveGreen" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="200" /> <Button x:Name="save" Clicked="Save" Text="Edit" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>`

My plan was to save the content of the entry between closing the apps like this:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        location.Text = Preferences.Get("path", "C://");
    }

private void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        if(save.Text == "Edit")
        {
            save.Text = "Save";
            location.IsReadOnly = false;
        }
        else
        {
            save.Text = "Edit";
            location.IsReadOnly = true;
            string path = location.Text;
            Preferences.Set("path", path);
        }
        
        
    }
```

But whenever I use Preferences.get() / Preferences.clear() / Preferences.set() I get the error message shown below.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B4ws.png)

Edit Edit:
[Project Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMJDO.png)

Comment: did you read and follow the instructions for configuring Essentials?  You have not posted any code demonstrating what you are actually trying to do so its difficult to give you specific advice.  Please read [ask] for guidance on writing on-topic questions.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added some more information above.
I followed the Getting Started Guide of Essentials. Was not sure, if I had to do the Android-specific guide, tried that and it did not find the Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init() Method.

Comment: What platform are you testing this on - UWP, MacOS, etc?

Comment: I'm running on a Windows. So UWP.
Don't know if that information helps, but the Windows App has the Target framework .NET Framework 4.7.2 and the Shared .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: Did you follow the UWP specific instructions in the setup?  Do you have the nuget package installed in every project?

Comment: Yes, it's installed on every project. On the Documentation of Essentials it says "No additional Setup required" for UWP

Comment: there is a blue box marked **Important!** that says "If adding to a UWP project ensure Build 16299 or higher is set in the project properties."

Comment: Could you help me, how I found out the build version or upgrade it? If I go into the properties, I can't find anything about that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/application-page-project-designer-uwp?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thank you already for your help. I added a screenshot of my property window in the second edit.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487648/how-to-resolve-not-implemented-exception-with-plugin-geolocator-package.